# use of static keyword

Tags: java

I wrote a very simple program in java to get used with the use of static keyword.But i am getting the output as 0. I am not able to find the reason for that.I am a beginner in  java .Can anyone please suggest a solution,also please do explain why such an problem was encountered ...My code is as following :

```
public class Cube{

    static int length;
    static int breadth;
    static int height;

    public static int volume(final int i, final int j, final int k){
        return length * breadth * height;
    }

    public static void main(final String args[]){
        System.out
            .println("volume of the cube is : " + Cube.volume(10, 20, 30));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing you did not try without the `static` keywords present. Because you would get the same result, which would indicate that it was nothing to do with the `static` keyword.

Comment: Using a decent editor such as Eclipse would have helped you solve this, since it would warn you nothing was done with i, j and k.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure eclipse would warn you about unused method parameters unless you crank the settings way up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`int` fields, `static` or not, are initialized as `0`.

You should multiply your operands (`i * j * k`) or assign to your static `int` fields.

Comment: thanks a lot eljenso ....i had never thought of such a problem in functions.thanks again , that i'll be careful not to make such silly mistakes again.

Answer (score 5):

Changing your method to this:

```
public static int volume(final int i, final int j, final int k){
    return i*j*k;
}
```

will give you value you wanted.

Also, read @eljenso's answer for more details.

What you probably wanted is this:

```
public static int volume(final int i, final int j, final int k){
   this.length = i;
   this.breadth = j;
   this.height = k; 

   return length * breadth * height;
}
```

You encountered a problem since values `10, 20, 30` are passed to `i, j, k`, but you didn't assign them to `length, breadth, height`.

And by the way, you don't really need `static` in this case. This would be a better design for your class:

```
class Cube{

    int length;
    int breadth;
    int height;

    public Cube(int length, int breadth, int height) {
        this.length = length;
        this.breadth = breadth;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public int volume(){
        return length * breadth * height;
    }

}
```

and it can be used as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Cube c = new Cube(10, 20, 30);
   System.out.println(c.volume());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will always `return 0` because length & breadth & height are initially 0;

```
public static int volume(final int i, final int j, final int k){
    return length * breadth * height;
}
```

Change it like that and it will work

```
public static int volume(final int i, final int j, final int k){
    return i*j*k;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason being when you call:

```
return length * breadth * height;
```

These variables are enclosed within an object that has not been initialized and you do need to instantiate it by using the new keyword if you want to go object oriented route. You would want to use static if there is no need to encapsulate the data of length, breadth and height.

Answer (score -2):

```
public class cube{
    static int length=20;
    static int breath=30;
    static int height=10;

    public static int volume( final int i, final int j, final int k){
        System.out.println("i=" + i + "j= " + j + "k= " + k);
        return length*breath*height;
    }

    public static void main(final String args[]){
        int a;
        a=volume(10, 20, 30);
          System.out.println(" area of cube " + a);
    }
}
```